# R: plotting a function, "not a graphical parameter"

Tags: r, plot

I've been using R for only a month, so bear with me. I wrote and plotted the following function:

```
func.1 <- function(x) {(-log(x))/(1+x)}
plot(func.1, from = 0, to = 6)
```

which worked, but now I am trying to write and plot a function to approximate the derivative with the difference quotient:

```
diff.quot <- function(x, h = .0001) {(func.1(x+h)-func.1(x))/h}
plot(diff.quot)
```

All of the above code runs fine until I try to change the value of h in the plot function. I want to plot diff.quot with different h values **all with the same function**, but I can't:

```
plot(diff.quot, from = 0, to = 6, h = .01)
```

Running this code gives me the following warning: "In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : "h" is not a graphical parameter". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with having the second argument `h` to `diff.quot`. Try removing the `h = .01` from the plot call (`diff.quot` will use the default value `h = .0001`).

Comment: @vincentmajor But how can I plot `diff.quot` with different `h` values without making additional functions? I just wanna use the same function to make multiple plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `curve` instead of `plot` like this:

```
curve(diff.quot(x,h=0.01), from = 0, to = 6)
```

[image]